# Finding E[Y] and V(Y) for Continuous Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics

I've been at this one for a while:

A random variable $X$ follows the distribution $$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} Cx^2&,\quad -2\leq x \leq 1\\0&,\quad \text{Otherwise}\end{cases}$$and  $Y\triangleq X^2$.

Find E[Y] and Var[Y].

I calculated C = 1/3.

I've tried $\int_b^a yf(y) dy$ for E[Y] and a similar formula using $y^2$ instead of $y$. The integrals were executed piecewise.

I could use some help, as all of my attempts (variations on the above two strategies) have been dead wrong.  The similar question on the board does not appear to address the calculation of these variables.

Comment: Have you already evaluated the value of $C$? Please provide as much information as possible.

Comment: Yes, C = 1/3. P( X >= 0) = .8888

Comment: You might want to read this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Since $\int_{-2}^1 f_X(x)dx=1$ we have$$C={1\over 3}$$also $$\Pr\{Y<y\}{=\Pr\{X^2<y\}\\=\Pr\{-\sqrt y<X<\sqrt y\}\\=\begin{cases}0&,\quad y<0\\\int_{-\sqrt y}^{\sqrt y}{x^2\over 3}dx&,\quad 0<y<1\\\int_{-\sqrt y}^{1}{x^2\over 3}dx&,\quad 1<y<4\\1&,\quad y>4\end{cases}\\=\begin{cases}0&,\quad y<0\\{2\over 9}y^{3\over 2}&,\quad 0<y<1\\{1+y^{3\over 2}\over 9}&,\quad 1<y<4\\1&,\quad y>4\end{cases}}$$therefore$$f_Y(y){={d\over dy}\Pr\{Y<y\}\\=\begin{cases}0&,\quad y<0\\{\sqrt y\over 3}&,\quad 0<y<1\\{\sqrt y\over 6}&,\quad 1<y<4\\0&,\quad y>4\end{cases}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use: $\mathsf E(Y)=\mathsf E(X^2)$, the "Law of the Unconscious Statistician" and $\mathsf {Var}(Y)=\mathsf E(X^4)-\mathsf E^2(X^2)$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y)&=\int_{-2}^1 x^2\cdot\frac {x^2}3~\mathrm d x\\[3ex]\mathsf{Var}(Y) &= \int_{-2}^1 x^4\cdot\frac {x^2}3~\mathrm d x-\mathsf E^2(Y)\end{align}$$